Displaying latest date until a new data upload happens
Hello everyone i have a table that contains text, the table name is "top_issue"
Existing data:



Upload Date
Created At
issue




2024-07-01
2024-07-01
the files are bugged


2024-07-01
2024-07-01
Issue 1


2024-07-02
2024-07-02
Issue 2


2024-07-02
2024-07-02
Issue 3


2024-07-03
2024-07-03
Issue 4


2024-07-03
2024-07-03
Issue 5


2024-07-03
2024-07-03
Issue 6


2024-07-04
2024-07-04
Issue 7


2024-07-04
2024-07-04
Issue 8


2024-07-04
2024-07-04
Issue 9


2024-07-04
2024-07-04
Issue 10



I want to show when it's on 4th, 5th July, and onwards appears like this



Upload Date
Created At
issue




2024-07-04
2024-07-04
Issue 7


2024-07-04
2024-07-04
Issue 8


2024-07-04
2024-07-04
Issue 9


2024-07-04
2024-07-04
Issue 10



If there's a new data upload on 10th July it will appear like this:



Upload Date
Created At
issue




2024-07-10
2024-07-10
Issue 11


2024-07-10
2024-07-10
Issue 12



Here is my exsiting DAX:
CALCULATE(max(top_issue[created_at]),ALL(top_issue))

Is there any change that i need to use?

you can update the measure like below.
MEASURE =
VAR _maxdate =
    MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )
VAR _maxdate2 =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Created At] <= _maxdate ),
        'Table'[Created At]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( MAX ( 'Table'[Created At] ) = _maxdate2, "y" )



MEASURE =
VAR _maxdate =
    date(selectedvalue(year),selectedvalue(month),selectedvalue(day))
VAR _maxdate2 =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Created At] <= _maxdate ),
        'Table'[Created At]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( MAX ( 'Table'[Created At] ) = _maxdate2, "y" )


Can you do this if the slicer like this?

pls see the last measure i added in this answer.

One last question, how i setting the filter from the measure?

you can try to create a column and filter the column to 'y'
Column = if('Table'[Created At]=max('Table'[Created At]),"y")


or you can create a measure and in the visual filter set that measure to be 'y'
Measure = if(max('Table'[Created At])=CALCULATE(max('Table'[Created At]),all('Table')),"y")



How about to choose the date like "2024-07-05" until "2024-07-09", is the data from "2024-07-04" still appeared?  When i try your answer data from "2024-07-04"  is disappeared

so you have a date range filter? what column will you use to filter the date?

For date range filter, i use calendar table as like "DimDate" in tutorials
